# I am trying to automate the popup that accepts cookies but in order to view cookies popup one must be in EU region. How do i use VPN in cypress?

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, automation, cypress, vpn

I tried using `export NO_PROXY=145.239.2.231,bookmundi.com` in the terminal before running cypress but didn't work. The cypress browser doesn't support the VPN changed from the web extensions.

Are there any scripts that could be written inside a program or every time before running cypress we have to manually set proxy environment variables?

I tried the script below as well

```
    Cypress.Commands.add(
      "mockGeolocation",
      (latitude = 30, longitude = -98) => {
        cy.window().then(($window) => {
          cy.stub(
            $window.navigator.geolocation,
            "getCurrentPosition",
            (callback) => {
              return callback({ coords: { latitude, longitude } });
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
    cy.mockGeolocation();
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.visit(
      "https://www.bookmundi.com/kathmandu/short-everest-base-camp-trek-8738"
    );
  });
```

Comment: I know it is not the cheapest way to solve it but maybe you can use https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/local-testing/proxies-firewall-vpn where you can easily change location, anyway you are going to pay monthly for EU VPN?

Comment: There's a thread on Cypress' github with a few different solutions for mocking geolocation: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2671

Comment: I used codes of geolocations but still no popup is seen https://i.imgur.com/PMfWFp5.png. The popup looks like this https://i.imgur.com/F2mS2S1.png